# Perform some function before calling another function

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am making an image slider. When user clicks on an image:

1. Image slides and comes in front
2. On the next click the image is flipped and enlarged
3. On the next click the image returns to its original size and position

On selecting other images the same steps happen.  What I want to do is this: suppose I select an image and the image flips and enlarges. Then I directly click on another image, so I want to write function that before enlarging the new image, the first image should come back to its original size and place.

How to do this?

```
    var status=1;
function flipIt(obj){
//$(obj).wrap("<div class='centerImage'></div>")



 console.log("value before Function status   "+status);

if(status==1)
{
alert("i am From JS IF part");
    $(obj).animate({"left": "-=30px","opacity": "0.65"},"slow");
    $(obj).animate({"height":"400px","width":"350px"},30);


  // initial        w295   h354
 $(obj).css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
 $(obj).css("-webkit-transition","all 1.0s linear");
 $(obj).css("transform-style","preserve-3d");
 $(obj).css("transition","all 1.0s linear");

 $(obj).css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(180deg)");
 $(obj).css("transform","rotateY(180deg)");
 //$(obj).css("box-shadow","-5px 5px 5px #aaa");

 status=0;
 console.log("after if value set status   "+status);
}
else
{

//alert("i am From JS Else part");
    $(obj).animate({"left": "+=30px","opacity": "0.99"},"slow");
    $(obj).animate({"height":"354px","width":"295px"},30);

 $(obj).css("-webkit-transform-style","preserve-3d");
 $(obj).css("-webkit-transition","all 1.0s linear");
 $(obj).css("transform-style","preserve-3d");
 $(obj).css("transition","all 1.0s linear");


 $(obj).css("-webkit-transform","rotateY(0deg)");
 $(obj).css("transform","rotateY(0deg)");
 //alert("apply css");
    status=1;
    Removecss();

 console.log("ater else value set status   "+status);

}
```

Comment: If you found one or more of the answers to this question helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-up) and/or [marking one answer as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), to help future visitors find the information they're looking for more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your situation can be abstracted to having a list of things, and when the user selects one of the things something happens with it (the image is flipped and enlarged, in this case). When the user selects another of the things in the list, you want to reset the effect on the first one.

One way to achieve this is to set a css class on the selected thing, say, `.flipped-and-enlarged`. Whenever you then transform any object in the list, you first do a reverse operation on any object that has this class:

```
function flipAndEnlarge(obj) {
    $('.flipped-and-enlarge').reverseFlipAndEnlarge();

    // do the rest of your stuff
}
```

This way, if you do it correctly, there can never be more than one flipped and enlarged image at any time.

---

Note that using `.reverseFlipAndEnlarge()` as in the code example above requires writing it as a jQuery plugin. Doing that is [really easy](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) and something I strongly recommend, but if you really don't want to you could probably do something like `reverseFlipAndEnlarge($('.flipped-and-enlarged'))` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try declaring a variable that will hold the name, class, or id of the current viewed/enlarged image then call it before the second image is click like this.

```
 var previousImage = $(this).attr('class');
```

and on the if try putting another if to check if the variable that holds the previous' image attr is empty like this

```
 if(yourFirstStatement){
    if(previousImage != ''){
        //doTheResetOfImageSize();
     }
   //doYourImageChangeSizeAndOtherAnimationThing..
 }
```

Hope this help you..:)
cheers....